# Problem with FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving

I am very beginner to Mathematica and also a new user on Stack Exchange. I just need to find solution to the equations. I found an example similar to my problem on the internet. When I put following equations and press Enter, it doesn't work.

```
eq1 = 18.4 == 16.989*x*u^2 + ((400*y + 24.7)*v^2)/19.62;
eq2 = 19.4 == 16.989*x*u^2 + ((66.667*z + 26.9)*w^2)/19.62;
eq3 = u == v + w;
eq4 = x^-0.5 == -1.8*Log[10, (0.792 + 0.0004618*u)];
eq5 = y^-0.5 == -1.8*Log[10, (0.792 + 0.0004618*v)];
eq6 = z^-0.5 == -1.8*Log[10, (0.792 + 0.0004618*w)];

FindRoot[Evaluate[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6}], {u, 0.0001}, {v, 
  0.00005}, {w, 0.00005}, {x, 0.01}, {y, 0.01}, {z, 0.01}]
```

Comment: Did you try Shift + Enter?

Comment: I just did and it gave me this error. FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5,eq6} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {6} at {u,v,w,x,y,z} = {0.0001,0.00005,0.00005,0.01,0.01,0.01}. >>

Comment: You need to use Shift+Enter on all of the equations too.

Comment: I did and it provided good solutions for u,v,w but for x, y and z, the solution is not realistic

Answer (score 3):

Try `NMinimize` to find directly a global solution:

```
 NMinimize[{1, eqs}, {x, y, z, u, v, w}]
 (* {1., {x -> 30.1198, y -> 30.0984, z -> 30.1134, u -> 0.183938, v -> 0.0420541, w -> 0.141884}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work. What problem do you see?

```
eqs = {
   eq1 = 18.4 == 16.989*x*u^2 + ((400*y + 24.7)*v^2)/19.62,
   eq2 = 19.4 == 16.989*x*u^2 + ((66.667*z + 26.9)*w^2)/19.62,
   eq3 = u == v + w,
   eq4 = x^-0.5 == -1.8*Log[10, (0.792 + 0.0004618*u)],
   eq5 = y^-0.5 == -1.8*Log[10, (0.792 + 0.0004618*v)],
   eq6 = z^-0.5 == -1.8*Log[10, (0.792 + 0.0004618*w)]
   };


sol = FindRoot[
  eqs, {u, 0.0001}, {v, 0.00005}, {w, 0.00005}, {x, 0.01}, {y, 
   0.01}, {z, 0.01}]

(* {u\[Rule]0.18393770061120188`,v\[Rule]0.042054105197920355`,w\
\[Rule]0.14188359541328152`,x\[Rule]30.11976613288159`,y\[Rule]30.\
09839805926534`,z\[Rule]30.113430477073248`} *)

eqs /. sol

(* {True,True,True,True,True,True} *)
```

Comment: Sir, Thank you so much for your time. I am getting the same values. But for x,y,z the values are not so realistic considering the physical problems

Comment: What values did you expect? Did the internet article propose a different solution to these equations that can be checked?  It is curious that x, y ,z are all very close to 30. Is it possible there is a factor or offset not accounted for in your equations?

Comment: I'd like to point put that `FindRoot` finds only _one_ solution to the equations and that these equation may have more than only one solution.

Comment: @DavidKeith: Sir the value of x,y,z should be around 0.1

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Sir, what do you suggest I should do now?

Comment: Sir, I have made some changes to the equations above. I am getting this now: "Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision \
within 100 iterations. "